# Make sidebar tab selected by default in shiny when using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using renderUI for the first time.  When I run the app there is no tab selected by default; when defining the UI outside of the server the first tab is normally selected by default.

Any idea why this happens, or how to specify that the first tab should be selected by default on startup?

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "header") 

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebar"))

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Radial Networks', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$body <- renderUI({
    dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
         tabItem(
           tabName = 'Chords', h2(fluidRow(
             box(plotOutput('plot'), type = 'html',  width = 6, height = '870px')
           )))))})

 output$sidebar <- renderUI({
   dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
     menuItem("Radial Networks", tabName = "Chords", icon = icon("adjust"))))
 })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_bar()
  })

}

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one argument to your tabItem():

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)


header <- dashboardHeader(title = "header") 

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("sidebar"))

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("body"))

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Radial Networks', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$body <- renderUI({
    dashboardBody(
       tabItems(
         tabItem(
           tabName = 'Chords', 
                        h2(fluidRow(box(plotOutput('plot'), 
                        type = 'html',  
                        width = 6, 
                        height = '870px')
           )))))})

 output$sidebar <- renderUI({
   dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
               menuItem("Radial Networks", 
                     tabName = "Chords", 
                     icon = icon("adjust"),
                     selected = 1)))
 })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl))) +
      geom_bar()
  })

}

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This would be because I had you put in the wrong location. Apologies. It needs to be in the sidebar call. I edited above.

Comment: This still doesn't work, although as per this page: https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/behavior.html it should.  I also tried ```selected = TRUE`` which also had no effect. This is perplexing

Comment: same problem here, selected seems not to be effective.